# App crashing while trying to send picture to server

Tags: php, android, image, server

1.while I'm trying to send a picture that I take to server the application crashes and it's show that there is something in line 101
and this is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.th3hokage.pfev1, PID: 25157
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.th3hokage.pfev1.SendPic.ImageUploadToServerFunction(SendPic.java:155)
                  at com.example.th3hokage.pfev1.SendPic$2.onClick(SendPic.java:101)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11090)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23647)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

2.The code of the method that Send to server and The Top of the Activity where I've instanced the ImageView , this almost the whole code except some secondary methods

```
   public class SendPic extends Activity {

ImageView imageViewHolder;

EditText imageName;

ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

Intent intent ;

public  static final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;

Bitmap bitmap;

boolean check = true;

String GetImageNameFromEditText;

String ImageNameFieldOnServer = "image_name" ;

String ImagePathFieldOnServer = "image_path" ;

String ImageUploadPathOnSever ="" ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.send_pic);

Button CaptureImageFromCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
 imageViewHolder = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Button UploadImageToServer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 imageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

 EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCamera();

 CaptureImageFromCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {

   intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 7);

  }
  });


public void ImageUploadToServerFunction() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStreamObject ;

    byteArrayOutputStreamObject = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ImageViewHolder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    // Converting bitmap image to jpeg format, so by default image will upload in jpeg format.
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, 
    byteArrayOutputStreamObject);

    byte[] byteArrayVar = byteArrayOutputStreamObject.toByteArray();

    final String ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar, 
 Base64.DEFAULT);

    class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            // Showing progress dialog at image upload time.
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SendPic.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

            super.onPostExecute(string1);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog after done uploading.
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // Printing uploading success message coming from server on android app.
            Toast.makeText(SendPic.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Setting image as transparent after done uploading.
            ImageViewHolder.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

            HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

            HashMapParams.put(ImageNameFieldOnServer, GetImageNameFromEditText);

            HashMapParams.put(ImagePathFieldOnServer, ConvertImage);

            String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(ImageUploadPathOnSever, HashMapParams);

            return FinalData;
        }
    }

    AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();

}
```

Comment: Please share the code or function which is doing the job of sending to server. Also first check whether the instance of Bitmap is not null before sending

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Null Pointer Exception simply means you are trying to use a object or an instance which has not yet been initialized or set null. Please make sure whether the bitmap instance has been properly instantiated and NOT NULL. Will still recommend you to share relevant code to address your problem in a better way.

Comment: @Kishan I've just added the code of the method

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ImageViewHolder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

should be

```
ImageView someImage= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
bitmap  = ((BitmapDrawable) someImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

You are accessing getDrawable() of ImageViewHolder Class rather than its object that you must have created.

You are missing:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageViewHolder.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Only once you have got the image back in onActivityResult(), you should then send that do code for sending it to the server. Not before that, because before that the ImageView has not Bitmap set.

As per your code REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE must be equal to 7.
i.e. REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE  = 7

Modify your Camera Capture intent like below:

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
```

Comment: I have already created the object and it's ImageViewHolder ,and it's not a class

Comment: You should call getDrawable() on the ImageView instance

Comment: I've already done that because ImageViewHolder  it's already an instance of ImageView

Comment: @C.yasser please share the code where you have instantiated this ImageView as ImageViewHolder

Comment: @C.yasser You are using ImageViewHolder with capital I. It should be "imageViewHolder" notice the small I.

Comment: does it have any effect ? I've tried with imageViewHolder and nothing changes

Comment: You are starting the Image Capture and waiting for result by calling startActivityForResult(). But you have not captured the result by 
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}

Comment: I did the changes that you told me but it still crushing , i think I have also to put.extra() data that gonna be captured

Comment: can u verify whether you are getting the image after being captured by your camera back to your activity?

Comment: Also update your code so that i can see where you are calling this function - ImageUploadToServerFunction()